# Min and Max values with ngx-mask package

Tags: angular, regex, input, form-control, ngx-mask

How can I set **Mininmal** and **Maximal** values for input, using ngx-mask and RegExp patterns (for example, I need to set pattern for 0-20 only numbers). Is it possible to do with ngx-mask?

In component.html:

```
<input
    mask="someMask"
    [patterns]="customPatterns"
>
```

In component.ts:

```
class Component {
  customPatterns = {
    // ... some Patterns
  }
}
```